# Dynamic HTML image loading using Javascript and Django templates

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to load a specific image using `javascript` in a `django` template, but seem to be running into an issue based on the way `django` tags are formatted.

I have a standard `django` static asset source in an `img` tag like below:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/folder/logo1.svg' %}" id="orgLogo" alt="Logo" height="100px"/>
```

I am displaying data from `django` lower on the page like so:

```
<a id="orgName" class="side_nav_item">{{ thing.org_name }}</a>
```

What I would like to do is have the `img` `src` change based on the value of `thing.org` inside the `django` tags.

I originally thought `jquery` would be the best option, but it doesn't seem to play nice with `django` tags:

```
$(document).on('load', '#orgName', function(){
    $('img').attr('src','{% static 'img/folder/''+$('#orgLogo').val()+' %}');
});​​​​​​
```

I get error because of the single quotes required as part of the `django` syntax.

I after I was able to get the basics of this `javascript` function to work, I was planning on using a `javascript` switch statement to test for specific values and assign an image (e.x. logo1.svg, logo2.svg, etc.) to each value (e.x. org1, org2, org2) `thing.org` can load (it's a pre-defined set of values that's not long and not likely to change).

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Can you use double quotes in js instead of single? Or perhaps store `thing.org_name ` in a JS var and then use that var instead of the string itself?

Comment: Think about it: the `{% static %}` template tag is evaluated by your back-end, when producing an HTML document. It doesn't exist on the front-end so it's not available anymore when your HTML/javascript reaches the browser and your javascript runs. So: create a dummy URL javascript variable (`var baseURL = "{% static 'img/folder/ %}"`) somewhere, and in your javascript manipulate this baseURL by appending the correct value.

Comment: And always check your javascript source code in your browser developer tools to see if django generated the correct variables if things don't go as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine stuff that is evaluated on the back-end, on your server (template tags) and stuff that's evaluated on the front-end, inside the end-user's browser (javascript): Your `{% static %}` template tag needs to be evaluated by Django **before** an HTML document is sent to the browser. You're  trying to mix javascript evaluated variables into the `{% static %}` tag but that makes no sense since they get evaluated at completely different points in time (and on different computers).

You can use template tags to create strings of course and then use that later in javascript:

```
var baseURL = "{% static 'img/folder/' %}"
$(document).on('load', '#orgName', function(){
    $('img').attr('src', baseURL + $('#orgLogo').val());
});​​​​​​
```

If you look at the HTML source file in your browser developer tools you'll see this:

```
var baseURL = "https://mycdn.net/static/img/folder/"  // or whatever your STATIC_URL is
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this without using `javascript`.

Here is the working code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% with 'img/folder'|add:thing.orgName|add:'.svg' as image_static %}
   {% static image_static %}
   {% endwith %}
   {% load static %}" id="orgLogo" alt="Logo" height="100px"
/>
```

The image file has to be the same name as the value of `thing.orgName`, but for my use case, that's not a problem because those names will likely never change or change very, very rarely.